# Return id based on existence of multiple value in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, collections, mongoose-schema

I want to return id based on certain condition like if a user value doesnot exist and both phone and email field matches with search condition with no available userId then i want to get the id of that specific row.If the userid exist it will not return anything.The idea of the query something like this:

```
db.records.find( { userId: { $exists: false } } )

db.records.find( { phone: "A", email:"B" }, { id: 1} )
```

how can i merge this query into one and return the only id in mongodb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the queries with commas:

```
db.records.find( { userId: { $exists: false },phone: "A", email:"B" }, { id: 1} )
```

Here's an example:
https://mongoplayground.net/p/V_HL7WQqoiO